# Form validation with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, html

There are two places to put form validation when developing with rails - Model class in rails or 'required' property in html5 on the very page. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use both.** The `required` attribute (and other client-side validation methods) provides users with validation before submitting, enabling them to fix their errors before they submit. But ultimately, you *have* to check all incoming data server-side as well, to be sure that you don't save anything invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use client-side validation without the server-side one because HTML or JS could easily be altered.

Comment: You should *use* it, but you should not *rely* on it.

Comment: If you can't rely on it, don't use it >_<

Comment: If it's helpful for the user, use it (but back it up).